# Can a popular question be kicked off the hot network question list?

Tags: discussion, support, on-topic, specific-question

I asked a question here that was receiving views and votes from the hot list and then it stopped. Marked as off topic although 12 people up voted it but it only took 5 to close it. I'm not complaining I just want to know if getting put on hold kicks you out of the hot list?

[Could a person float in the air in a bubble? revised](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/110241/could-a-person-float-in-the-air-in-a-bubble-revised)

Comment: How did that question end up in the math stack? It should have gone to the physics stack instead.

Comment: @Renan Probably because the [OP is suspended on Physics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/148704/muze) and the comments state that this is not the first time (the profile "About You" indicates similar things). If you would like to ask for the real reason you need to ask MichaelKjörling, the mod who migrated the question (this can be seen on [the revision history](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/posts/110241/revisions)).

Comment: @Renan, looks like Maths SE rejected the Migration too

Comment: @Muze, you did, and that's indicated by a comment I made to [this question](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/107696/genetically-modified-inbreeding).  You've had a couple of questions deleted, and the original with the comment chain is gone (I don't have the rep to see deleted questions).  Your selective memory aside, my invitation is to caution.  You've asked a LOT of questions that aren't worldbuilding questions.  Complaining that a question with upvotes was closed and then saying you're not complaining just raises (at least my) ire.

Comment: @JBH I know how I feel about SE and it is not the place to ask stupid pointless questions. If I ask them here it is because I value the answers here over all other websites. Your opinion and stand on my questions matter to me and please know that everything you say matters to me as a student of SE. When I have 20 k reputation I will help other how you have helped me.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Closed questions are excluded](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/61343/56541) from the hot network questions list. This means that, yes, if a hot question gets put on hold, it will be removed from the list.

Comment: Nice to see you again!